# Assigning multiple styles on an HTML element

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting out with HTML and I'm having a trouble assigning multiple styles to a text.
I'd like to create a title with two properties:

1. Centered
2. Font: Tahoma

I have tried this one:

```
<h2 style="text-align:center";"font-family:tahoma">TITLE</h2>
```

but it doesn't work...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put the whole style attribute value in `" "` and not each one of them separately. `style="text-align:center; font-family:tahoma"`

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In HTML the style attribute has the following syntax:

```
style="property1:value1;property2:value2"
```

so in your case:

```
<h2 style="text-align:center;font-family:tahoma">TITLE</h2>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

The syntax you used is problematic. In html, an attribute (ex: style) has a value delimited by double quotes. In that case, the value of the style attribute is a css list of declarations. Try this:

```
<h2 style="text-align:center; font-family:tahoma">TITLE</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck on the same issue and I hope this helps someone someday:

```
<style>
  .red-text {
    color: red;} p {font-size: 16px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this does set two properties, a good answer should relate the CSS to the question asked, rather than post some as-is code and just "hope that it helps."

Answer (score 0):

The way you have used the HTML syntax is problematic.

This is how the syntax should be

```
style="property1:value1;property2:value2"
```

In your case, this will be the way to do

```
<h2 style="text-align :center; font-family :tahoma" >TITLE</h2>
```

A further example would be as follows

```
<div class ="row">
    <button type="button" style= "margin-top : 20px; border-radius: 15px" 
    class="btn btn-primary">View Full Profile</button>
</div>
```